# Using Python's __get__ descriptor for non-class attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes, python-descriptors

Using `__get__` descriptor I would like to achieve something like that:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, wrapped_value):
        self._wrapped_value = wrapped_value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self._wrapped_value

wrapper = Wrapper('foo')
assert type(wrapper) == type('foo')
```

It turned out, that `__get__` descriptor gets called only if `Wrapper` instance is a class attribute of some other class, it does not get called when `Wrapper` instance is a standalone object (not bound to any class attribute).

Is there a way to make `__get__` descriptor work in non-class attributes?

The main goal is to implement wrapper, which when used acts like value it wraps (I know it doesn't sound useful at first glance but there are some use cases in which this would be helpful). So maybe there is other way to achieve this without using `__get__` descriptor?

Comment: I'm not sure you could ever get `type(wrapper)` to return the wrong value, and even less sure that it would be a good idea.  Can you provide more examples of situations where you would use `Wrapper`? There may be other ways to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: Well, `__get__` descriptor exists exactly for that purpose - to 'hide' true identity of an object and let it act as an object of a different type. This is an example from official Python 2 documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-example

Comment: In above example following code would not raise AssertionError:

`assert isinstance(m.x, int)`

But this works only if an instance of `RevealAccess` class is a class attribute of `MyClass`. I want it to work also if `RevealAccess` instance is a standalone object.

Comment: The descriptor code works because `type()` is called on the the object returned by the descriptor, not the descriptor itself.  What I'd like to understand is whether you need `type()` to return the type of the wrapped object, or whether it would be enough to have wrapper control access to the methods/attributes of the wrapped object, which could be done using `__getattribute__`

Comment: I would like to achieve following result: when `Wrapper` instance is used the `_wrapped_value` object is used instead, i.e.:
`wrapper = Wrapper(1); assert wrapper is 1`

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Before you've mentioned usage of `__getattribute__` - what exactly you had in mind? I can't find any other solution so I will try to explore this one if it will suite at least some of my needs.

Comment: After doing some solid thinking I came to conclusion that trying to wrap objects in such aggressive manner seems like a serious dirty-hack and might be even consider dangerous. The point is, that **I would not recommend anyone to try to achieve what I was aiming to accomplish**, which is i.e. `wrapper = Wrapper(1); assert wrapper is 1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your Wrapper class to control access to the wrapped classes attributes you can use the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) magic method.

Say we have a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo(object):

    def bar(self):
        return 'bar'

    def baz(self):
        return 'baz'
```

Let's say that we are interacting with some code that we do not control that requires the output of `Foo.bar()` to be upper case, and we don't want to explicitly call `.upper()` in our code.

We can create a wrapper class that intercepts calls to `Foo.bar()`, but transparently allows access to `Foo`'s other methods (this is essentially the [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)).

```
class Wrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # If 'name' isn't an attribute of this class,
        # get it from the wrapped instance.
        return getattr(self._wrapped, name)

    def bar(self):
        # Intercept calls to the wrapped instance's bar() method.
        return self._wrapped.bar().upper()



>>> wrapper = Wrapper(Foo())
>>> print wrapper.baz()
baz
>>> print wrapper.bar()
BAR
```

This Wrapper class would not be reported as a `Foo` by `type` or `isinstance` checks, but otherwise it can be used in place of `Foo` as long as the calling code relies on [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) rather than (unpythonic) explicit type-checking.

Intercepting magic methods such as `__str__` has to be done explicitly.  This is because these methods are always [looked up](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup) directly on an instance's class, so `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` are bypassed.

So to override `Foo.__str__` you would need to do:

```
class Foo(object):

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'I am a Foo'


class Wrapper(object):

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._wrapped)

>>> wrapper = Wrapper(Foo())
>>> print wrapper
I am a Foo
```

Comment: Here's an example of what I would think of as a wrapper class - let me know how it matches/differs from what you are trying to do.

Comment: I thought that maybe `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` implementation in `Wrapper` will be able to handle calls to i.e. `wrapper.__str__` and redirect them to `self._wrapped.__str__` via `getattr` function. If this would be possible then all dunder method calls on `Wrapper` instance could be redirected to dunder method calls of `self._wrapped`. Unfortunately this is not possible.Do you know why getting i.e. `__str__` attribute is not possible by `__getattr__` method? Is this because `__str__` method is not in `Wrapper.__dict__` nor `wrapper.__dict__`?

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is exactly what I was afraid of - I need to manually override each dunder method and don't forget about any of them otherwise my `Wrapper` would not behave exactly as wrapped object (which I'm aiming at). So I need to find full list of available dunder methods and override them all. But still - overriding `is`, `isinstance` and `type` checks will not be possible, right? Or maybe there are corresponding magic methods which are called when such checks are performed?

Comment: @KonradKocik, AFAIK, `is` and `type` cannot be intercepted.  You could have a look at the tools in the [abc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module.  But to be honest, this level of emulation seems pointless; if you want something that just behaves _exactly_ as the original object, just use the original object.

Comment: Well - behaves _exactly_ the same, but with one exception: `Wrapper` itself will be mutable while still wrapping immutable object :)